# Динамические структуры данных, работа с файлами

Tags: c++, visual-studio, структуры

Необходимо написать программу, условия следующие:

База данных: Студент.

Создать базу данных со следующей структурой:

char* fam; //Фамилия

char* name; // Имя

char* faculty // факультет

int grup // номер группы

Создать функции:

1. Поиск по фамилии
2. Фильтр по номеру группы
3. Сортировка по алфавиту
4. Добавление нового элемента в базу
5. Распечатка таблицы данных
6. Выход из программы

Программа есть, но поиск по фамилии происходит некорректно, и в какой-то момент проверки программа вылетает (одна из причин: ConsoleApplication4.exe вызвал срабатывание точки останова, каждый раз - на одной из строк в функции freeList). Также, если записывать имя и фамилию на русском, в какой-то момент они превратятся в набор бессмысленных символов.

Не могу понять, чем вызваны все эти проблемы. Помогите, пожалуйста. :)

UPD: все проблемы решены, кроме одной: функция, которой необходимо искать студента по фамилии, вовсе не находит студента, а наоборот, исключает всех студентов с этой фамилией. Ломаю голову и не понимаю, что не так.

````
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

struct student {
    char* name;
    char* surname;
    char* faculty;
    int group;
};

struct list {
    list* next;
    student data;
};

struct ans {
    student** s;
    int count;
};


...

// найти студента по фамилии
list* findStudentLastName(list* H) {
    list* s = NULL;

    while (fgetc(stdin) != '\n');

    cout << "Enter last name: ";
    char surname[255];

    for (; H != NULL; H = H->next) {
        if (strcmp(H->data.surname, gets_s(surname)))
            s = addKnot(s, H->data);
    }

    return s;
}

...

    while (command) {
        printMenu();
        command = inputInt();

        switch (command) {
        case 1: {
            students = addKnot(students, addStudent());
            break;
        }
        case 2: {
            printAllStudents(students);
            break;
        }
        case 3: {
            list* s = findStudentLastName(students);
            if (s == NULL) cout << "There are no students with this surname. " << endl;
            else printAllStudents(s);

            for (list* c = s; c != NULL;) {
                freeList(c->data);
                list* temp = c->next;
                free(c);
                c = temp;
            }

            break;
        }
        case 4: {
            list* s = findStudentsToAGivenGroup(students);
            if (s == NULL) cout << "There are no students on this group. " << endl;
            else printAllStudents(s);

            for (list* c = s; c != NULL;) {
                freeList(c->data);
                list* temp = c->next;
                free(c);
                c = temp;
            }

            break;
        }
        case 5: { //сортировка в алфавитном порядке
            sortList(students);
            printAllStudents(students);
            break;
        }
        default: if (command) cout << "There is no command with number " << command;
        }
    }


...

    cout << "Обращайтесь!\n";

    return 0;
}```
````

Comment: ознакомьтесь, пожалуйста: [mcve]

Comment: мирэа, первый курс?

Comment: @S.H., миэт, второй

Comment: Чтобы мой вопрос был не совсем впустую: вы пишете "в какой-то момент они превратятся в набор бессмысленных символов". Чтобы с этим бороться - попробуйте в самом начале функции main добавить два вызова:   SetConsoleCP(1251);
SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

Comment: Собственно, осталась единственная проблема: функция поиска по фамилии лишь исключает студентов с этой фамилией...

Comment: > Собственно, осталась единственная проблема: функция поиска по фамилии лишь исключает студентов с этой фамилией - а нельзя там как то "знак поправить", чтобы она наоборот, исключала студентов с не этой фамилией?